# Pure Rotation in Computer Graphics

Tags: graphics, rotation, 2d, computer-science, image-rotation

What is called a pure rotation in computer graphics? Does it mean the transformation applied on any matrix is `only rotation`?
If so, then how the angles between intersecting lines are preserved by pure rotation?

Comment: Yes, it means only rotation

Answer (score 0):

From a geometric perspective, angles are of course preserved.

From a mathematical prospective, you can show both length and dot product are unchanged under rotation.  This means that if you have three points A, B, and C and let Ax, Bx, Cx be the location of these points after a rotation:

1. The distance from A to B is the same as the distance from Ax to Bx.
2. If you let V be the vector from A to C and and W be the vector from B to C, then V·W is the same as Vx·Wx.

This is just painful math.

Since the dot product of two vectors is the cosine of the angle between them times the length of each of the two vectors, you have that rotations are angle preserving.